# unable to compile java program from command prompt in Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7

I have set Path and ClassPath environment variables. But still I am unable to compile my HelloWorld.java program from command prompt. Please help me compile and run java program from command prompt

CLASSPATH C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib

Path C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\

Comment: Can we get your error message?

Comment: Can we see some code where it fails?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add JDK's directory to your path variable (not your JRE's path as you are actually doing it). JDK is usually in:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_xx\bin\
```

Where `xx` stands for update number you have installed. Then just compile HelloWorld by using:

```
C:\Your\dir\where\HelloWorld\Is\>javac HelloWorld.java
```

In case you don't have **JDK** installed and you have only **JRE** installed, you won't be able to compile anything. You will need to download and install **JDK** properly to do Java Development in general (including compiling stuff).

Comment: From where should I install jdk?

Answer (score 1):

You need a JDK to compile classes rather than a JRE.  The JRE is used for running Java applications (the JDK can also do this, but you cannot distribute the JDK).

When you have installed a JDK, ensure that the JDKs bin directory is on your path.  You can then compile your Java classes using the javac.exe command.

Answer (score 0):

PATH must be like

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin (This is on my system)

That is must point to JDK's bin not the jre's bin.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should also have your current directory in the CLASSPATH.

set CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib;

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing `cd C:\examples\ch01\ATM` then press enter and that will change your directory. This allows you to write for example `java ATMCaseStudy`, then press enter. This should work if you placed your directory in C with your JDK in the same place.